# Largest possible value of $P(A \cap B)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are events with $P(A)+P(B)>1$. Show that the
>   largest possible value of $P(A \cap B)$ is $  \min(P(A), P(B))$.

I suspect I'm supposed to use $P(A \cap B) = P(A)+P(B) -P(A \cup B)$ but I've no idea how. I also understand that from this we get $P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)$. However, I don't know how to use that.

Comment: You can get $P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)$ and $P(A\cap B)\leq P(B)$. So, you can combine to $P(A\cap B)\leq \min(P(A),P(B))$. It's a bit peculiar that the question you were given phrases that as "the largest possible value of $P(A\cap B)$ is $\min(P(A),P(B))$."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can argue that $\Pr(A \cap B) \le \Pr(A)$, then you can also argue that $\Pr(A \cap B) \le \Pr(B)$ by symmetry, giving the desired result.

If you need a formal argument to show that $\Pr(A \cup B) \ge \Pr(A)$, consider writing $A \cup B$ as a union of the disjoint events $A$ and $B \setminus A$.

Comment: Both of these are just specific instances of the fact that $U\subseteq V\implies \Pr(U)\leq\Pr(V)$, right?

Comment: @MPW: Indeed.  If the OP needs a hint about proving what you stated, writing $V$ as the union of $U$ and $\bar U \cap V$ would help, too (where $\bar U$ denotes complementation).

Comment: Thanks @d125q I noted both facts but couldn't string them together.

Answer (score 2):

Using that $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$, you get that $P(A\cap B) \leq P(A)$ and $P(A \cap B) \leq P(B)$ (simply because $P(A \cup B)\geq P(A)$).

So you can say that $P(A\cap B) \leq \operatorname{min}\{P(A),P(B)\}$. Now, if $A=B$ then you get the equality, so that is the largest possible value.

Answer (score 2):

$A \cap B\subseteq A$; therefore $\Pr(A\cap B)\le\Pr(A)$.  In the same way, prove $\Pr(A\cap B)\le\Pr(B)$.